# Hibernate regex validation on fields doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I've got a simple regex, which should match only letters and numbers in last 4 chars of string:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$)
```

It works perfectly in [online tester](https://regex101.com/r/nP8kI7/2), but doesn't match if i use it with hibernate validation annotation on field:

```
@NotNull
@Length(min = 4, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$)")
private String test;
```

For example, it returns false for `1234.5678-abC2` string

Could you help me?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match the `.` character. Add `\\.` within the `[` `]`.

Comment: My regex should check that last 4 chars of input string don't contain special chars. So, `.` not supposed to be matched. I'm not sure that i understand you correctly. Coluld you please give an example?

Comment: You are assuming that the @Pattern annotation will return true if a substring regex match passes. If it isn't working then your assumption may not be true. Try adding .* in the beginning of your pattern string

Comment: please mark either of the answers below as the accepted answer for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

For future visitors, I would add the response of @hofan41 provided in the main OP comment.

> You are assuming that the `@Pattern` annotation will return true if a substring regex match passes. If it isn't working then your assumption may not be true. Try adding **.*** in the beginning of your pattern string.

In such a manner, the bean property validation annotations will look as follows:

```
@NotNull
@Length(min = 4, max = 25)
@Pattern(regexp = ".*([a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$)")
private String test;
```

Answer (score 5):

The pattern matches against the entire region as can be seen in the following [PatternValidator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/PatternValidator.java) code:

```
public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    if ( value == null ) {
        return true;
    }
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher( value );
    return m.matches();
}
```

...And from the documentation for [Matcher.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()):

> Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern.